# Visual Studio Code Search All Files

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, get a php function named "example". How do I find out what other files I use this function for? I just want to search the files in the workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the magnifying glass on the left side, put in the term, and press Enter / Return.

(Hit the little 3 dots to include/exclude files.)

Click the arrow to the left of the search box, and then you can do Search and Replace in files.

You can also find the functions specifically, as outlined here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#find-all-references-to-a-symbol